# Grunt - html minifier task fails

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am using `grunt-contrib-htmlmin` for my HTML files.

I added an exception for `node_modules` directory, so my `Gruntfile.js` looks like this:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
      pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

      htmlmin: {
        prod: {
          options: {
            removeComments: true,
            collapseWhitespace: true
          },
          files: {
            src: ['**/*.html', '!node_modules/'],
            dest: 'prod/'
          }
        }
      }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-htmlmin');
```

When I run `grunt build` what I get as a result in console is:

> Running "htmlmin:prod" (htmlmin) task
> Minified 1 files (1 failed)
>   
> Done, without errors.

I have 4 HTML files and none of them are minified and I can't even see the error. What I am missing here?

Comment: Are you really sure this is the only task that's being run? The task is called "htmlmin:prod" but the error message refers to "htmlmin:dist".

Comment: are all the files in the same location?

Comment: @Geraint Two files are inside a subdirectory called includes but since I am using '**/*.html' for the source that doesn't matter, does it?

Comment: Are you running as a production build? You don't have any settings for a dev env so maybe it is just doing one file by default

Comment: Yeah I am running as a production build. I don't need to minify them for dev.

Comment: I liked to move my html files into specific folder and minifiy them there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your specific error, but I do see problems with your grunt config.

First, when using the [Files Object Format](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files-object-format), you specify a src-dest mapping with the destination path as the key and the source path (or array of source paths) as the value. For example:

```
files: {
    'prod/minified.html': 'src/unminified.html'
}
```

With your current configuration, `src` is interpreted as a destination file path.

In order for you to use the `src` and `dest` properties in the way you are intending, you must use the [Files Array Format](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files-array-format).

```
files: [{
    src: ['**/*.html', '!node_modules/'],
    dest: 'prod/'
}]
```

Unfortunately, this will not yet get us to our expected output. There are a few problems we need to fix:

`prod/` is interpreted as a single destination path, rather than as a prefix as intended. We need to tell grunt to [build our files object dynamically](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically) by setting `expand: true` on our files object.

Next, we will need to set `flatten: true` in our files config to tell grunt to strip the paths of our source file paths when computing the destination file paths.

Thirdly, the pattern `!node_modules/` will exempt *only an exact* match, literally "node_modules/". To exempt all files under the node_modules folder, we must use the [globstar](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns) matching pattern, `!node_modules/**`.

Our result is the following:

```
files: [{
    expand: true,
    flatten: true,
    src: ['**/*.html', '!node_modules/**'],
    dest: 'prod/'
}]
```

Comment: Amazing, that worked. I was missing the flatten and the /** after node_modules. Thank you, you also helped me to understand the problem, not only solving it.